# Change image on page load according to database

Tags: php, ajax, json, function

Once my page (index.php) loads, there are images which represent whether a seat is taken or not. I am having difficulty making the image change to 'sold' from 'Available'.

The database has 2 columns: 
seatnumber (E.g A1) and Status (e.g 0) - If the status is zero the seat is taken.
I've got my script on index.php:

```
 <script>getSeats();</script>
```

Then in my getseats.php, its returning the data fine (tested in URL) so it returns:

```
 [{"seatnum":"A1"},{"seatnum":"A2"},{"seatnum":"A3"}] (
```

The seats previously sold stored in my database)

I'm struggling with the AJAX part, where it would change the image source of the seat from available to sold. Code shown below, but i dont think the majority is correct as i've been playing around with it for a while now.

```
function getSeats(){
    var myurl="scripts/getseats.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: myurl, dataType:'json', // JSON OBJECT
        success: function(taken){

        }
    })// end of success function
    else {

    }
```

An available seats file is available.if and a sold seat is sold.gif.

If anybody could take the time to help me id really appreciate it!

In a nutshell, i just want an image to change from available to sold if if the database status is 0.

getSeats.php:

```
<?php
 $noerrors=dbconnect();
 if($noerrors <> 0) {
  echo '{"errorcode":"'.$noerrors.'"}';
 } else {
  $query = "select seatnum from seats where status='0'";
  $link = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$link) {
   echo '{"errorcode":"3"}';
  } else {
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
   }
   $json=json_encode($rows);  
   echo $json;
  }
 }
 function dbconnect(){
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $noerrors = 0;
  $link = @ mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
  if (!$link) {
   $noerrors = 1;
  } else {
   $db_selected = @ mysql_select_db('bookings', $link);
   if (!$db_selected) {
    $noerrors = 2;
   }
  }
  return $noerrors;
 }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<td><img id = "A1" src="images/available.gif" style="border:none" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="sold(this.id)" /></td>
     <td><img id = "A2" src="images/available.gif" style="border:none" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="sold(this.id)" /></td>
     <td><img id = "A3" src="images/available.gif" style="border:none" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="sold(this.id)" /></td>
```

Comment: What does the HTML you want targeted look like?

Comment: Also, where does the database status come from? the getseats.php file looks like it just returns an array of seats but no status is associated with them. Does this mean that if the seat is not in the array that it is available?

Comment: Ive added the code requested, it only returns seats that have a status of 0 (Sold) from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go. Change this:

```
function getSeats(){
    var myurl="scripts/getseats.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: myurl, dataType:'json', // JSON OBJECT
        success: function(taken){

        }
    })// end of success function
    else {

    }
```

to this:

```
function getSeats(){
    var myurl="scripts/getseats.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: myurl, dataType:'json', // JSON OBJECT
        success: function(taken){
            if (taken) {
                 for (var i=0, l=taken.length; i<l;i++) {
                     $("#" + taken[i].seatnum).attr('src', 'sold.gif'); 
                 }
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getSeats();
});
```

Two things are happening here:

1) Document.ready function ensures that the DOM is ready to be interacted with before running your script

2) We loop through the response of the getseats.php script and set the img src of each seat with id `seatnum` to `sold.gif`

Hope this helps!